# Differences in behavior after passing arguments to function in Python

Tags: python, function

For this code below:

```
def add_minor(person):
    person.append('math')
def switch_majors(person):
    person=['physics']
    person.append('economics')
John=['computer_science']
Tim=John
add_minor(Tim)
switch_majors(John)
print(John, Tim)
```

Can someone explain why the output is:

`['computer_science', 'math'] ['computer_science', 'math']`

How come "John" did not change major?

In addition, for the two pieces of code below:

```
a=[3,4]
b=[6,7]
def do_stuff(a,b):
    a+=[5]
    b+=[8]
    return a,b
do_stuff(a,b)
```

and

```
a=3
b=5
def do_stuff(a,b):
    a+=1
    b+=2
    return a,b
do_stuff(a,b)
```

How come the values for a and b changed in the do_stuff function when they are lists but not when they are numbers?

Lastly, why does the follwing code return None values?

```
a=[3,4]
b=[6,7]
def do_stuff(a,b):
    return(a.append(6), b.append(8))
do_stuff(a,b)
```

Thanks

Comment: Because in some cases, you *mutate* the object you pass in, e.g. in `add_minor`. In the other case, in `switch_majors`, you *do nothing with the object passed in*, indeed, you *always* just assign a new list object to that variables, `person=['physics']` and then *mutate that* object. You could just remove the argument from the function and it would work *exactly the same*

Comment: `int` objects are *immutable*, they cannot be mutated, only neew objects are created. In contrast, `list` objects can be mutated. `a+=[5]` mutates the object when `a` is a list. `a+=1` creates *a new* int object and assigns it to `a`. Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Conversely, if you want Tim to be an independent copy of John and you know John is a simple list (i.e. it just contains strings/numbers) without nested lists/dictionary/set, you could use `Tim = list(John)` or for a deep copy, `Tim = copy.deepcopy(John)` see https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_minor(person):
    person.append('math')
```

here person is not *mutated*, you call `append` on the object that was passed as argument, explaining why Tim is modified

```
def switch_majors(person):
    person=['physics']
    person.append('economics')
```

after first line, person refer to a totally new object ( `['physics']` ).
when you append `economics` to the array, it is the new object that is modified, the initial value `John` that was passed as argument remains untouched.

More globally, modifying the value of an argument (like a += 6) does not modify it outside the function scope explaining why append works in function : it does not modify the variable but rather the internal state of the object (i.e. the list elements)

Lastly :

```
a=[3,4]
b=[6,7]
def do_stuff(a,b):
    return(a.append(6), b.append(8))
do_stuff(a,b)
```

`do_stuff` return (None,None) because `a.append(6)` and `b.append(8)` both returns None, that is normal behaviour since the append method does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

1st question:
You changed it in line `person=['physics']`
The same is with this easier example

```
person=[1,2,3]
person.append(4)
print(person) # prints [1,2,3,4]
person=[1] # assigning to [1] again
print(person) # prints [1]
```

2nd question:

Lists are mutable
Numbers don't change because int is immutable
https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747
Also this is useful:
There are 2 ways to add to list, lets say you have this line `example=[1,2]`:

```
example+=[3]
print(example) # [1,2,3]
```

```
example.append(3)
print(example) # gives the same output [1,2,3]
```

3rd:

You need to change it to this becase append() doesn't return a value

```
a=[3,4]
b=[6,7]
def do_stuff(a,b):
    a.append(6)
    b.append(8)
    return(a, b)
print(do_stuff(a,b))
```